# Are there any supported Selenium (or other) scripts to test Azure B2C and Azure AD authentication?

Tags: selenium, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-platform, uat

I'm using Azure Pipelines and am interested in having an automated Selenium (or similar) test verify the authentication flow from my WebApp to the IDP and back.

I would like to include tests for incremental consent, and other features prior to the code being merged into the master branch, or before the code is deployed to UAT or production.

Does any pre-existing work exist to allow me to test for this?

Comment: What's the problem in your automated selenium test. With automated selenium test, you don't need to the redirect URL and just specify credential after the page being loaded. Related thread: https://discussions.qualys.com/thread/17328-selenium-authentication-with-apps-using-azure-active-directory-b2c